# Dumping microwave oven energy on electronic device

Tags: electrical-engineering

Microwave oven generate around 1 KW of power. If this energy is dumped on a electronic device, say wifi router, gsm phone or fm receiver etc, what will happen? Will the devices be damaged? 
By dumping I mean the magnetron at a distance of 1m or less from the electronic device and assume body cage absent.

Comment: A comment will help the new contributors to understand why their question is off-topic, a negative vote without any explanation is too confusing for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the device will be damaged. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vI8JTUql3bQ for reference... Sure, inside the body cage, the microwaves are bouncing around and may be more concentrated, but even with no cage, the effect is the same - microwaves hitting thin metal (as on a PCB) causes arcing, and consequently damage. You may not get an explosion, but you definitely won't get working devices.

Comment: what if isolated components like transistors or diodes with bond wire leads are subjected to the dumping?

Comment: With any radiation, your basic options for what happens are 1) Passes through (light through glass, microwaves through tupperware), 2) Reflects (light off mirror, microwaves of thick flat metal, like the microwave walls), or is absorbed (light onto matte black surface, or microwaves onto water molecules). Which of those do you think will happen with an electronic component? If it's not 1) or 2), then you'll certainly get damage.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it is not clear what will happen with components with bond wire. bond wire will act as antennae. i dont think antennae will be damaged because of 1 kw of rf power, rather i am not sure. will the induced voltage be enough to kill the device?

Comment: I don't have any experimental data to point you towards - my experience and instinct tells me that the components will be damaged. If you doubt it, just put a transistor in a(n old) microwave, retreat to a safe distance, and find out...